# RoR - Event Calendar undefined method `calendar'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Event Calendar to generate a calendar for my events, but I'm getting a weird error. Every time I run webrick I get an "undefined method 'calendar'" error, but if I change anything in the events_helper and save without restarting the server, the error disappears! Has anyone seen such an error?

This is the line the message is referring to in the events_helper.rb (line 3)

```
def event_calendar
    # args is an argument hash containing :event, :day, and :options
    calendar event_calendar_opts do |args| 
      event = args[:event]
      %(<a href="/courses/#{@course.id}/events/#{event.id}" title="#{h(event.name)}">#{h(event.name)}</a>)
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

-- Full Trace:

```
app/helpers/events_helper.rb:20:in `event_calendar'
app/views/events/index.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_events_index_html_erb__2839012149448078506_2185002760'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/Users/moshark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__3962713512247968028__process_action__3396197975695833499__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:206:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
sass (3.2.1) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2917286435426199189__call__17875809250747617__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.0.1) lib/quiet_assets.rb:20:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/moshark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/moshark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/moshark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: what is events_helper.rb line 3?  and in `calendar event_calendar` is `calendar` some other helper/function ?? or event_calendar_opts

Comment: Oh sorry I mean this function is in the events_helper, and the error points to calendar which is found in line 3 in this piece of code here. Yes I installed the events_calendar gem which implements that function in its calendar_helper (when I opened up the gem to check it out)

Comment: seems rails is unable to find out the `calendar` function.. you might have to `require` it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try including EventCalendar::CalendarHelper into your helper

Comment: Oh thank God! it works! Thank you very much! Could you please tell me why we needed to do that?

Comment: because the gem adds the helper to controller context (making it available in the views). But this does not mean that helpers can automagically 'cross-reference' each other.

Comment: I had the same issue today after month of using event-calendar. Thanks for the tip, it probably saved me hours of weird debugging!

Comment: I also ran into this issue, oddly enough. As with @AkyRhO it's been working just fine inside my helper for months but only seemed to break today. I haven't done any updates on my end. This fix resolved it however.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to require the `event_calendar` in addition to including it in your Gemfile.

Use following syntax:

```
gem 'event-calendar', :require => 'event_calendar'
```

Comment: I looked at my gem file, and found that I already do that unfortunately .. Should I maybe require it somewhere else?

Comment: I tried requiring it in the controller/ helper but it still won't work.. would adding the full trace help?